# How to make a standard image/installation for an new PC in AD?

Tags: windows, active-directory, disk-cloning

Surely, there must be a way to clone the programs/configurations of one PC to another one, such that the new PC can be installed automatically in Active Directory.

You cannot configure 100 new PCs by hand.

For example:

A school would like to have Office and a programming tool installed for 100 PCs. The network configuration must work and the shared folders shall already be visible on Users Desktop.

How would I do that?

Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to create an custom WIM Image with the needed configuration of the computer in order to provision it with an .ISO File or Windows Deployment Server to all Computers. Programs like NTLITE can extract an .WIM File from an .ISO image where an WIN PE Image (available through the windows ADK) can extract an .WIM Image File from an existing Windows Installation.

If you have to account for long term support with reinstalling and updating computers and updated images in the future I would recommend using an windows deployment server with an PXE Installation.
Then you can create your own task sequence which can execute different kind of scripts or installation after another.

There are multiple guides on the official microsoft website [like this one](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/deployment/windows-deployment-scenarios-and-tools) which explains the requirements for such an installation and configuration.